# Multiple hypothesis testing correction with Benjamini-Hochberg, p-values or q-values?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Given a list of p-values generated from independent tests, sorted in ascending order, one can use the [Benjamini-Hochberg procedure](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/%7Eybenja/MyPapers/benjamini_hochberg1995.pdf) for [multiple testing correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate#Independent_tests). For each p-value, the Benjamini-Hochberg procedure allows you to calculate the False Discovery Rate (FDR) for each of the p-values. That is, at each "position" in the sorted list of p-values, it will tell you what proportion of those are likely to be false rejections of the null hypothesis.

My question is, are these FDR values to be referred to as "**[q-values](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-31/issue-6/The-positive-false-discovery-rate--a-Bayesian-interpretation-and/10.1214/aos/1074290335.full)**", or as "**corrected p-values**", or as something else entirely?

**EDIT 2010-07-12:** I would like to more fully describe the correction procedure we are using. First, we sort the test results in increasing order by their un-corrected original p-value. Then, we iterate over the list, calculating what I have been interpreting as "the FDR expected if we were to reject the null hypothesis for this and all tests prior in the list," using the B-H correction, with an alpha equal to the observed, un-corrected p-value for the respective iteration. We then take, as what we've been calling our "q-value", the maximum of the previously corrected value (FDR at iteration i - 1) or the current value (at i), to preserve monotonicity.

Below is some Python code which represents this procedure:

```
def calc_benjamini_hochberg_corrections(p_values, num_total_tests):
    """
    Calculates the Benjamini-Hochberg correction for multiple hypothesis
    testing from a list of p-values *sorted in ascending order*.

    See
    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate#Independent_tests
    for more detail on the theory behind the correction.

    **NOTE:** This is a generator, not a function. It will yield values
    until all calculations have completed.

    :Parameters:
    - `p_values`: a list or iterable of p-values sorted in ascending
      order
    - `num_total_tests`: the total number of tests (p-values)

    """
    prev_bh_value = 0
    for i, p_value in enumerate(p_values):
        bh_value = p_value * num_total_tests / (i + 1)
        # Sometimes this correction can give values greater than 1,
        # so we set those values at 1
        bh_value = min(bh_value, 1)

        # To preserve monotonicity in the values, we take the
        # maximum of the previous value or this one, so that we
        # don't yield a value less than the previous.
        bh_value = max(bh_value, prev_bh_value)
        prev_bh_value = bh_value
        yield bh_value
```

Comment: your reference about q-value should be http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.aos/1074290335

Comment: The Benjamini-Hochberg procedure is not for calculating the FDR, it is for controlling the FDR (keeping it under a predefined threshold)

Comment: Your question, as it stands, is difficult to understand. What do you mean by "referred to" ?

Comment: @robin Many thanks for your comments. I apologize for my confusion of terminology. I have updated the question to include a more complete description of our correction procedure, in the hopes that it provides clarification. I have also updated the q-value link; thanks for pointing me to that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As Robin said, you've got the Benjamini-Hochberg method backwards. With that method, you set a value for Q (upper case Q; the maximum desired FDR) and it then sorts your comparisons into two piles. The goal is that no more than Q% of the comparisons in the "discovery" pile are false, and thus at least 100%-Q% are true.

If you computed a new value for each comparison, which is the value of Q at which that comparisons would just barely be considered a discovery, then those new values are q-values (lower case q; see the link to a paper by John Storey in the original question).

Comment: We sort the test results in increasing order by their un-corrected original p-value, then, iterating over the list, calculate the FDR expected if we were to reject the null hypothesis for this and all tests prior in the list, using the B-H correction using an alpha equal to the observed, un-corrected p-value. We then take, as what we've been calling our "q-value", the maximum of the previously corrected value (FDR at iteration `i - 1`) or the current value (at `i`), to preserve monotonicity. Does this sound like the procedure you described in your second paragraph?